# Boiled chicken breast skin tastes like soap

Tags: chicken

I often buy full chicken in supermarkets and boil it. I noticed that its outermost breast skin part (only skin, and only that part where you would expect nipples) tastes like soap. At first I thought that maybe I didn't clean the dish-washing liquid from the fork completely or something, but then I realized that this happens with ALL chickens I bought... They were from different sources, of different sizes and complexity. Does any body know the reason? Thanks

Comment: Chickens don’t have nipples... but to be more serious, are you boiling them in plain water? I mean you aren’t boiling then in lye water?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not soap that you taste.  At least here in the US, most chicken bound for the supermarket is sprayed or dipped in a bleach solution.  It could be you are picking up on that, but it is not a taste I've ever noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Not an uncommon problem apparently.

https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2671284

https://ask.metafilter.com/83528/Wash-your-mouth-out

that last link is someone cooking it in a pan. But there is some logic going on in those discussions. Soap is - animal fat + other ingredients. Some of the discussion is suggesting that perhaps your water is contributing the 'other' ingredients. Or perhaps the phosphates used by butchers is the 'other' ingredients.

Solutions? try washing your raw chook just in water, paper towel dry. Also maybe do an experiment and use bottled water. Do those two actions separately, as it might be your water is the problem. (loner term solution being install a water filter on your tap).